# how to pull data from a table based on date ranges?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbvisualizer, amazon-athena

Is it possible to have a sql query which pulls data per date and customer?
Use case:
Table 1 has items purchased by customers, with data of purchase
Table 2 has all of the support tickets customers may have reached out for.

I am looking to filter table 2 data to customers who have purchased (in table 1) but also have contacted us either 10 days before or after the purchase.

So if Bob purchases a screw driver on 6/1/2022 (on table 1). i am looking to pull any calls from Bob between 5/21/22 to 6/10/22

A picture to help illustrate:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code using date range:

```
SELECT
   support_id, customer, date_of_support, details
FROM 
   table_1 AS t1
JOIN 
   table_2 AS t2
ON 
   t1.customer = t2.customer 
WHERE 
    daterange(date_of_purchase - '10 days'::interval, date_of_purchase + '10 days'::interval, '[]') @> date_of_support
```

The `'[]'` is included in the `daterange` to make the upper bound inclusive. In other words it will bump the upper `date` up one.

**UPDATE**

From here [Date/time functions/operators](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/datetime.html) this would seem to be possible in Athena/Presto:

```
...
WHERE 
   date_of_support BETWEEN date_of_purchase - interval '10 days' 
    AND date_of_purchase + interval '10' day;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing, no luck, ::interval doesnt seem to work with Athena (it uses presto)

Comment: What about substituting `cast('10 days' as interval)` for `'10 days'::interval`?

Comment: i think i got it to work with this, need to test on larger data tomorrow. "where
date_diff('day', support_date, purchasedate)<10 or
date_diff('day', purchasedate, support_date)<10 and date_diff('day', purchasedate, support_date)>0"

Comment: See **UPDATE**. If you want to stick with your solution would it not be `<=10`?

Comment: I was running into negative days, so i added the >0. here is the latest which fixes some of the issues, trying yours in 2 mins. "where
(date_diff('day', support_date, purchasedate)<10 and date_diff('day', support_date, purchasedate)>0) or 
(date_diff('day', purchasedate, support_date)<10 and date_diff('day', purchasedate, support_date)>0)"

Comment: running into "unknown type: interval error. perhaps our presto is not up to date to support interval.

Comment: See my change from `interval '10 days'` to `interval '10' day`. This matches what is in the Presto docs.

Comment: If the requirement does indeed include '...contacted us either 10 days before or after the purchase" then you are going to have negative days.

Comment: Thanks that worked! it matches the results from my prior one and is easier to read!